# How can I alter the default behavior of iTunes 10.7 to suppress some UI elements like the store?

Tags: itunes, macos, high-sierra

I like iTunes 10.7 and I've been sticking with it ever since it came out and hope to avoid updating it now that I run macos High Sierra.

I'm trying to figure out how to delete/remove/hide the 'iTunes store / iTunes Match ' option in the left panel.

I’m OK disabling SIP (system integrity protection, patching / modifying system frameworks - hex editing files, hacking on a plist file etc.. I've had luck with editing other apps this way such as calculator, but I knew what to look for.)

With iTunes I'm clueless. Has anyone reverse engineered this app or know specifically how to edit this specific version of iTunes on macOS?

Comment: What did you do in Calculator?

Answer (score 1):

In the current version of iTunes (12.8), this is very easy:

1. Go to iTunes > Preferences
2. Go to Restrictions
3. In the "Disable" list, check "iTunes Store"

I would assume the same feature is present in iTunes 10.7, but given that it's six years old and I can't find a screenshot of its preferences window, I can't confirm that for sure.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm afraid this option does not exist in 10.7.